# What is making vertical scrollbars appear on my website?

Tags: templates, xhtml, scrollbar, blogger

I am having a problem with my website ( based on Blogger). There are vertical scrollbars appearing eventhough there they are not needed and they don't even move up or down. Can you please help me figure out what is causing them to appear ?!

this is my website url to check it : http://gsalafi.blogspot.com/p/ar.html

and this is my blogger template code : http://pastebin.com/V9j9mu8J

Please tell me if you note any errors in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your css, or perhaps replace your `<body></body>` with `<body style="overflow: hidden; width:1024px; margin:0px auto 0px auto;"></body>`.

Remember:

`overflow-x: hidden;`
Would hide any horizontal overflow, and insuring any horizontal scroll bars disappear.

`overflow-y: hidden;`
Would hide any vertical overflow, and insuring any vertical scroll bars disappear.

`overflow: hidden;`
Would remove both scroll bars, and all overflow content.

Comment: Unfortunately , this is not a good fix. This will remove scrollbars permananetly and my website has a search box which displays results and that is why scrollbars are needed for that. I used to have a template that doesn't show scrollbars except after they are needed.

Comment: Then edit the bodies width by a fraction: <body style="overflow: hidden; width:1000px; margin:0px auto 0px auto;"></body>. Or only suppress x scroll bars. <body style="overflow-x: hidden; width:1024px; margin:0px auto 0px auto;">

Comment: I fixed the problem by adding this CSS : body, .body {
padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

Comment: First , please tell me if the CSS code is correct ? Now , I have one problem left. I want to add margins or paddings to the top of my website. I want to add white space at the top . How I can I do it ?

Comment: You can create a top margin by inserting this into your css in the appropriate place. margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px. Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp.

Comment: I cant tell you if your code is correct. It has no errors, only hundreds of warnings.

Comment: problem still persists. I can not seem to remove the code causing the vertical scrollbars to appear. !!